# Why was my question about "Kirby mass attack hidden switches" closed as a Duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked earlier where the [hidden switches of the Dedede resort](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110055/kirby-mass-attack-dedede-resort-hidden-switches) of Kirby Mass Attack were.  It has a different message that says, "Keep an eye out for hidden switches on some stages".  It is not the same question that asks where to find them in the snow levels, or that it has a message that says you have to press a button found on a specific stage, it doesn't say anything about buttons.

Comment: Now that the question is on meta, you're going to need to clarify what your other question was about.  From the explanation here, it sounds like you're looking for a list of where to find every single switch.

Comment: Hi @lize!  Here on meta, we ask questions about ***about asking questions***.  Your question was migrated, because it fits that mold.  Now as fbueckert points out - it would be helpful if you could explain how your questions is different.  It seems like both questions are seeking hidden switches which control access to a hidden level.  Are you saying there are more than one pair of such switches and levels?